# How to display date in custom format with Compact Framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I need to display a date using the Compact Framework, in the following format :

> TUE,02/16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
Dictionary<string,string> days = new Dictionary<string,string>();
days.Add("Monday", "MON");
days.Add("Tuesday", "TUE");
days.Add("Wednesday", "WED");
days.Add("Thuesday", "THU");
days.Add("Friday", "FRI");
days.Add("Saturday", "SAT");
days.Add("Sunday", "SUN");
//Edit
MessageBox.Show(days[DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString()] + DateTime.Now.ToString( " MM/dd"));
```

Comment: Dictionary<string, string> days = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 days.Add("Tuesday", "Tue");
days.Add("Wednesday", "Wed");
days.Add("Thursday", "Thu");days.Add("Friday", "Fri");
days.Add("Saturday", "Sat");
days.Add("Sunday", "Sun");
days.Add("Monday", "Mon");
List<string> opDateSource = new List<string>();
 string dte = (DateTime.Now.AddDays(0).ToString(days[DateTime.Now.AddDays(0).DayOfWeek.ToString()] + " MM/dd/yy"));     I tried this but the output is coming as "6on 08/06/15". Why is Mon not coming at all. ?

Comment: Just replace this row
string dte = (DateTime.Now.AddDays(0).ToString(days[DateTime.Now.AddDays(0).DayOfWeek.ToStrin‌​g()] + " MM/dd/yy"));
with
string dte = (days[DateTime.Now.AddDays(0).DayOfWeek.ToStrin‌g()] + DateTime.Now.AddDays(0).ToString( " MM/dd/yy"));

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dateTime method to display stuff like that.

```
DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
string longDate = currentDateTime.ToLongDateString();
MessageBox.Show(LongDate, "Today's date is");

//the string will now have value of for example Friday, January 30, 2010
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
new DateTime(2016, 2, 16).ToString("ddd,MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUpper();
```

The `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` ensures that you get exactly that format you've requested regardless of the device's configuration; if you omit that parameter you'd get a similar format, but in the current culture of the device.